# Cosa vuol dire "la strada fu al ciglio" in questo testo?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *L'isola*, di Giani Stuparich, ho letto questo testo che fa riferimento a un padre e suo figlio che stanno camminando su una strada sull'isola natale del padre:

> Improvvisamente **la strada fu al ciglio** e uno spettacolo mirabile si presentò agli occhi dei due uomini che quasi d'intesa si fermarono. Sotto di loro una folta ghirlanda di tenero verde, mosso e leggero, coronava un'ampia insenatura, un perfetto semicerchio, nella cui sabbia dorata un mare d'ametista, d'incantevoli trasparenze, veniva a cullarsi, arricciandosi all'orlo di sorridenti spume.

Ho cercato il termine ["ciglio" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ciglio/) e ho visto che può avere  questo significato:

> Orlo, lembo estremo d’una strada lungo un solco, un fosso, un canale, un precipizio

Capisco dunque che la strada possa avere un ciglio con questo significato, ma non riesco a capire il senso della frase "la strada fu al ciglio" nel brano sopra citato. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Potrebbe significare che seguendo la strada in salita sono arrivati al ciglio, cioè al margine della stessa (delimitato dall'orizzonte) che poteva interrompersi oppure proseguire verso il terreno sottostante.

Comment: concordo con l'interpretazione di abarisone; significa proprio che la strada era giunta al limite  e all'improvviso si interrompeva.

Comment: Credo che *ciglio* sia adoperato per [*ciglione*](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/ciglione)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il significato più probabile è che seguendo la strada in salita  padre e figlio siano arrivati al ciglio, cioè al margine della stessa (delimitato dall'orizzonte) che poteva interrompersi oppure proseguire verso il terreno sottostante.

Comment: Questo "margine" sarebbe la parte più alta di quel tratto di strada?

Comment: @Charo Esatto, la parte più alta che potrebbe terminare oppure proseguire in basso.